# Scroll multiple scrollable widgets in sync

Tags: scroll, dart, controller, flutter, synchronization

to put it simply:

**is there a way to have multiple sccrollable widgets (say, `SingleSchildScrollView`) together in sync?**

---

i just want 2 scrollables that can scroll the other as i scroll one.

this way i can use `Stack` to put them on top of each other and the one behind can scroll following the front one.

or maybe put them in another set of `Column` or `Row` so that they are separate, but still scrolls by just scrolling either one.

i tried using `controller` but it does not seems to be doing what i think it is.

---

Try the code below for example,
the "RIGHT" will be in front of the "LEFT" and if i try to scroll them, only the RIGHT will move. so how do i move them both together at the same time??

*please dont tell me to put the stack inside a `ListView`, that is not what i need.*

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final ScrollController _mycontroller = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body:
      Container(
        height: 100,
        child:
          Stack( children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _mycontroller,
              child: Column( children: <Widget>[
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
              ],)
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _mycontroller,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
              ],)
            ),
          ])
      )
}}
```

i believe this question has been asked before in multiple forums before but nobody has put a conclusion or solution to this at all. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170779/scrollcontroller-attached-to-multiple-scroll-views))

Comment: why would you want such strange ux design? why not to use one single scrolling view?

Comment: @pskink i just want to know how to scroll 2 widgets together. ultimately i wanted to make something like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yDT2RDyStT7UeFNn8oWS8QAPbzzwbsN5)

Comment: @pskink hey, i cant seem to open your link. can you paste the content to answer this question instead?

Comment: @pskink hey!! your piece of code is helping me out. its kinda working, with my previous pieces of codes i tried.. so far its looking good, i will try to add this to my project and see if it works as expected.. WILL UPDATE SOON!!!!

Comment: as i said: you should not follow that way: its a bad workaround

Comment: @pskink but so far its the only solution that has been doing what i wanted.

Comment: you should change your ui design instead

Comment: @pskink okay then. but thank you anyway :) it still helped me understand flutter better. cheers mate!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i managed to sync multiple scrollables by using their `offset`, utilizing their `ScrollNotification`.

here's a rough code example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  ScrollController _mycontroller1 = new ScrollController(); // make seperate controllers
  ScrollController _mycontroller2 = new ScrollController(); // for each scrollables

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body:
      Container(
        height: 100,
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>( // this part right here is the key
          Stack( children: <Widget>[

            SingleChildScrollView( // this one stays at the back
              controller: _mycontroller1,
              child: Column( children: <Widget>[
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
                Text('LEFT            '),
              ],)
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView( // this is the one you scroll
              controller: _mycontroller2,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
                Text('          RIGHT'),
              ],)
            ),
          ]),

          onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {  // HEY!! LISTEN!!
            // this will set controller1's offset the same as controller2's
            _mycontroller1.jumpTo(_mycontroller2.offset); 

            // you can check both offsets in terminal
            print('check -- offset Left: '+_mycontroller1.offset.toInt().toString()+ ' -- offset Right: '+_mycontroller2.offset.toInt().toString()); 
          }
        )
      )
}}
```

basically each `SingleChildScrollView` has its own `controller`.
each `controller` has their own `offset` values.
use the `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` to notify any movement, anytime they are scrolled.

then for each scroll gesture (i believe this is a frame by frame basis),
we can add `jumpTo()` command to set the `offset`s in anyway we like.

cheers!!

PS. if the list has different length, then the offset will be different and you will get a stack overflow error if you try to scroll past its limit. make sure to add some exceptions or error handling. (i.e. `if else` etc.)

Comment: @sivakumar check out my answer, that should take care of your problem

Answer (score 15):

I was just facing the same problem, and there's now an official package for that: [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller).

Using that package, you just have to create a master [`LinkedScrollControllerGroup`](https://pub.dev/documentation/linked_scroll_controller/latest/linked_scroll_controller/LinkedScrollControllerGroup-class.html) to keep track of the scroll offset and it'll then provide you separate `ScrollController`s (kept in sync) via [`LinkedScrollControllerGroup.addAndGet()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/linked_scroll_controller/latest/linked_scroll_controller/LinkedScrollControllerGroup/addAndGet.html).

Comment: I tested it, and it is nice if all the scrollable widgets have the same height. But my widgets have different heights, and I need something that doesn't take the actual pixel count, but the scrolled percentage. If someone has a solution for me please let me know.

Comment: For some details about using `linked_scroll_controller` you can check this blog post: https://www.flutter-demo.net/2022/12/how-to-create-linked-scroll-widgets.html

Answer (score 6):

if your UI is simple wrap both scrolling widgets - lets say two Column - with an opposite widget - like Row - then with a SingleChildScrollView
like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      //first column
      Column(),
      //second column
      Column(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

if it is complicated, you can use scroll controllers like this

```
  late final ScrollController scrollController1;

  late final ScrollController scrollController2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController1 = ScrollController();
    scrollController2 = ScrollController();

    scrollController1.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController1.offset != scrollController2.offset) {
        scrollController2.jumpTo(scrollController1.offset);
      }
    });
    scrollController2.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController1.offset != scrollController2.offset) {
        scrollController1.jumpTo(scrollController2.offset);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

and then add each scrollcontroller to each scrolling widget you have like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  controller: scrollController1,
  child: Column(), // column 1
)

SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  controller: scrollController2,
  child: Column(), // column 2
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your answer @Chris, I ran into the same problem and built my solution on top of yours. It works over multiple widgets and allows syncronized scrolling from any of the widget in the "group".

---

**PSA: This seems to be working fine, but I'm just getting started and this might break in the most fabulous way you could imagine**

---

It works using a `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` plus an independent `ScrollController` for each scrollable Widget that should be synchronized.
The class looks like this:

```
class SyncScrollController {
  List<ScrollController> _registeredScrollControllers = new List<ScrollController>();

  ScrollController _scrollingController;
  bool _scrollingActive = false;

  SyncScrollController(List<ScrollController> controllers) {
    controllers.forEach((controller) => registerScrollController(controller));
  }

  void registerScrollController(ScrollController controller) {
    _registeredScrollControllers.add(controller);
  }

  void processNotification(ScrollNotification notification, ScrollController sender) {
    if (notification is ScrollStartNotification && !_scrollingActive) {
      _scrollingController = sender;
      _scrollingActive = true;
      return;
    }

    if (identical(sender, _scrollingController) && _scrollingActive) {
      if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
        _scrollingController = null;
        _scrollingActive = false;
        return;
      }

      if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
        _registeredScrollControllers.forEach((controller) => {if (!identical(_scrollingController, controller)) controller..jumpTo(_scrollingController.offset)});
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that you register each widgets `ScrollController` with that helper, so that it'll have a reference to each widget that should be scrolled. You can do this by passing an array of `ScrollController`s to the `SyncScrollController`s constructor, or later on by calling `registerScrollController` and passing the `ScrollController` as a parameter to the function.
You'll need to bind the `processNotification` method to the event handler of the `NotificationListener`. That could probably be all implemented in a widget itself, but I'm not experienced enough for that yet.

Using the class would look something like this:

*Creating fields for the scollControllers*

```
  ScrollController _firstScroller = new ScrollController();
  ScrollController _secondScroller = new ScrollController();
  ScrollController _thirdScroller = new ScrollController();

  SyncScrollController _syncScroller;
```

*Initalize the SyncScrollController*

```
@override
void initState() {
  _syncScroller = new SyncScrollController([_firstScroller , _secondScroller, _thirdScroller]);
  super.initState();
}
```

*Example of a complete NotificationListener*

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: _firstScroller,
    child: Container(
    ),
  ),
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
    _syncScroller.processNotification(scrollInfo, _firstScroller);
  }
),
```

Obiously implement the above example for each scrollable widget and edit the `SyncController` (parameter *controller:*) and `processNotification` scrollController parameter (above *_firstScroller*) accordingly. You might implement some more fail safes, like checking `_syncScroller != null` etc., above PSA applies :)

Comment: Continuing down the road, I see why this would be not so optimal, performance suffers clearly if things start to grow

Comment: Man your solution with listening is so awesome. I like the way you've get rid of recursive scroll position changes and handled it as a separate Sync class.

Comment: I needed to set the initial offset for the scroll controllers and the linked_scroll_controller does not seem to support that now. This approach works in my case since I can set the offset for each ScrollController. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an ancient question, but might be useful for someone ..
the package [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller) is exactly what you're looking for, it performs much better than the `NotificationListener` or adding a listener to your scrollController and using `.jump` ..

```
  late ScrollController controller1;
  late ScrollController controller2;
  late LinkedScrollControllerGroup parentController;
  
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    parentController = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    controller1 = parentController.addAndGet();
    controller2 = parentController.addAndGet();
  }
```

and that's it, connect controller1 to first scrollable widget, and controller2 to the other, and they're synced.

Answer (score -1):

I found this one and worked for me

```dart
static final tracking = TrackingScrollController();

// implementation
child: ListView(
  controller: tracking,
```

and work on multiple pageview also.

Comment: Hi @malik kurosaki, could you expand your answer, it does't work. Why did you make it as static?

Comment: This is actually the best answer when using PageView and scroll views on each page that should be synchronized.

Comment: Does it make any sense? One instance of a ScrollController can not be used for multiple scrolling