# Flutter : make two listviews scrollable as one

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a screen that's scrollable (like the whole screen scrollable).

This is what I got know:

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[

                 Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: posts2b)),

            Expanded(child: ListView(children: posts2a)),
          ],
        );
```

It all works, but I want those listviews scrollable as one. So if you scroll down, the horizontal listview 'disappears'.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: so if you scroll on one of the the lists, the other one should scroll automatically, that's a bit weird?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for has already been fixed in this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859779/scroll-multiple-scrollable-widgets-in-sync

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: posts2b,
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: ListView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: posts2a,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`, set height for horizontal list and disable scrolling for vertical list by adding `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` ...

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, But there's an error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 743 pixels on the bottom.
The whole screen doesn't scroll....

Comment: In my case physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), worked .

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics worked really well.

Answer (score 5):

Use SizedBox() and give the option, shrinkWrap: true.

```
SizedBox(
              child: ListView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
...
),
SizedBox(
              child: ListView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
...
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by this approach -

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                        ListView(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          .
                          .
                          .
                        ),
                          ListView(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
                        ),
                      ]),
                    );
```