# Flutter - How to link three columns so that they scroll together

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have three columns inside a row. The contents of the columns are generated by a listbuilder getting data from a database. Right now each column scrolls individually but I need them to scroll as one. Is this even possible in flutter or should I have made a gridview instead of three separate columns?

Comment: add your code !!

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879937/6447123
It works using a `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` plus an independent `ScrollController` for each scrollable Widget that should be synchronized.

You can use `TrackingScrollController` too