# FLUTTER How do you properly implement a TrackingScrollController?

Tags: scroll, dart, controller, flutter, synchronization

similar question has been asked before [SEE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170779/scrollcontroller-attached-to-multiple-scroll-views)

basically i get a `Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.`

because i have multiple scrolls with the same controller.

**how do i use it properly then?**

the documentation literally said "scroll views that share a **single** TrackingScrollController."

Comment: i gave you a working code, didnt i? if so, what is NOT working?

Comment: @pskink hey!! yea it was working, i was implementing it wrong the first time. tried it again and it worked.. then i realized i have to make a controler for each and every scroll i make, so if i were to make 10 list, i would have to make 10 controlers for each. so i tried using the tracking controller, so i can only use 1, but its not working

Comment: ten lists? are you serious? thats why i told you that your UI/UX design is broken and what you are trying to do is a bad workaround

Comment: @pskink ok sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170779/scrollcontroller-attached-to-multiple-scroll-views)