# How to properly use ScrollController with multiple scroll positions?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a widget that consists of several scrolling widgets (list views and a custom widget). When I scroll any of those list views the custom widget must be scrolled as well. Just to be clear the custom widget isn't actually a scroll view, but a stateful widget that updates its viewport content when a scroll position of the list views is changed.

Currently I'm using a scroll controller for each list and listener to sync the positions by calling `jumpTo` for the other controllers. But this seems a clumsy way to achieve what I need.

`ScrollController` exposes the interface to control multiple positions, and because behind the scene it's `jumpTo` method just calls `jumpTo` for each `ScrollPosition` object in `positions` list, I hoped that there is a way to utilize this for synchronization of multiple scroll views by sharing the same controller. And it seems I'm not the only one who had the same idea ([ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170779/scrollcontroller-attached-to-multiple-scroll-views)). But the only recommendation I could find is to use a controller per scroll view, which I already do.

Clearly I'm not completely understand how to work with scroll views in Flutter. So my questions are the following. What is the purpose of `positions` in the `ScrollController`? What is the design decision behind it and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single `scrollController` for many scrollable widgets(ListView,Gridview,etc) the `scrollController` save each ScrollView in a `Iterable` so if you want to `jumpTo` you need to use the argument called `positions` which is a `Iterable<ScrollPosition>` type.
Somethin like this:

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();

PageView(
  controller: _pageController,
  children: <Widget>[
    _ListView(controller: _scrollController),
    _ListView(controller: _scrollController),
    _ListView(controller: _scrollController),
  ],
)

void _moveScroll(){
    _scrollController.animateTo(
              // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
              _scrollController.positions.first.maxScrollExtent, 
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), 
              curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
```